# Python Data extraction from a pop-up window

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get a specific data from a website, but this is a little bit complicated to understand so here is some images.
So, first, I'm on this page,
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZu9.png)

then I click on the icon in the middle and something pop,
[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6akjB.png)

then I have to click on this,
[almost there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ujyy.png)

And finally I land here
[arrival](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sP9C.png)

And I want to get all the names of the people here

So, my question is, is there a way to get directly this list with a requests ?
If yes, how do i have do to ? I can't find the URL of this kind of pop up and I'm a complete beginner with requests and all this kind of things..

(To get the name, I have to be connected on my account by the way)

So, since I don't know how to access to the pop-up windows, this is the only code I got :

```
import requests
 
x = requests.get('https://www.tiktok.com/@programm___r?lang=en',  headers={'User-Agent':'test'})

print(x.text)
```

I checked what it prints, and i didn't see a sign of the pop-up window

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic] and [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we cannot help if you don't post any code with the attempts you've made and specify where you got stuck.

Comment: Hey, I haven't made any code yet because I just don't know how to get information from the pop-up windows

Comment: @user2314737 I updated what I did but yeah like i said I don't think this is useful..

Comment: If it's an App maybe it offers an API for developers and you can use that, otherwise you cold rely on Selenium for Web automation. Hope this helps! But: your current question is still too vague to be considered for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey ! I already checked there is no API. And yeah i know selenium but this is not the question, I'm just asking if someone know how I can get the URL of this. And if it's possible to access it.

Comment: if page use JavaScript then you may not get it. `requests`/`beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. `requests` get only original HTML without JavaScript updates. Eventuall you can use DevTools in Firefox/Chrome to check if JavaScript doesn't read these data from other URL and then you may try to use this URL with `requests`.

Comment: if you have to be connected to see pop-up then you have to use `requests` to send login/password and get cookies which will inform other `requests` that you are logged in. And again you may use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome` to see what and where browser sends data to server when you login - and later you can try to use `requests` to send the saem data to the same URL.

Comment: alright, I had the same issue once I know what you mean, if you know what Javascript gets executed you can use Scrapy or even requests

Comment: okay thanks for your anwser ! I have ro admit I do not know how to do all the things you said but I'm going to try anyway !

Comment: Okay after many tries, I got some link but they all send 403 forbidden or doesn't exist, is there a way to still use them ?

Comment: your script may have to behave like read human using real web browser. You may have to use `Session()` to get cookies on main page and send them to other pages. You may have to use exactly the same `headers` in requests like you find in DevTools when you visit these pages.

Comment: I mean, I got forbidden without trying with Python, when I copy / paste the link by hand i got forbidden, can I make it work with session and headers ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get some sort of network interception tool like Burpsuite and watch the network traffic that comes through each time you click on each link along the way to your final destination, this should give you an endpoint you may be able to send your request too. I think this network information should also be available in the browser tools but I'm not sure. A potential issue here is that usually tokens and other information has to be passed down the chain along the way, which might make scripting something like this too hard.

So aside from that, with browser automation software like selenium, you could automate the process of getting to that point on the page, and be able to pull out the list you want once you're there. I've used selenium myself and it's really usable and well documented!